# PySimpleGUI Output box loses focus after clearing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface

I'm using `PySimplyGUI` to perform some basic input/output operations. One of the elements in my window is Output which displays script/executable terminal output as they run. I have another element in my window that allows the user to clear the output. The clear operation works fine, but all subsequent output is redirected to my terminal instead of the output box which remains empty.

Am I missing a line of code to reset the Output focus or something?

Here's my code for clearing the output:

```
if event in ('Clear Output'):
    window.FindElement('_output_').Update('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue wasn't due to element clear logic but my print statement for generating the output:

```
print(str(output), sep=' ', end='n', file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
```

Changing to defaults fixed the problem:

```
print(str(output))
```